# Cannot find Flask (among other packages) on Ubuntu 18 after installation

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask

I was trying to install flask-socketio on Ubuntu and in order to succeed, I read here on SO I should issue the following command: "sudo apt-get install python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev".

After that I just can't find gunicorn, flask, etc.

How can I solve this?

**Edit: I am not using VirtualEnv, so I install the modules using sudo apt-get install module name. Also, this is NOT duplicate, as the suggested answer speaks about VirtualEnvs.**

## ERROR on Console:

```
    File "/usr/local/bin/flask", line 7, in <module>
        from flask.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

Comment: I assume you ran `pip install flask`, are you sure you are using the right pip? (e.g. try `pip3 install flask` and `pip2 install flask`.

Comment: I am not using VirtualEnv or pip... I install the modules directly through sudo apt-get install <module name>

Comment: I have figured out the Python version changed on the system. Now I have to understand how to activate Python 3.6 back.

Comment: "in order to succeed, I read here on SO I should issue the following command:..." could you link the advice

Comment: "/usr/local/bin/flask" installed packages should never put anything into the "/usr/local/". You really should describe in more details what are you doing